# New Nest Cam Disappeared from SDM API

Tags: google-sdm-api

I have a new 2021 Google Nest camera (wired not battery) it was showing up fine through the SDM API but it has suddenly disappeared and only my doorbell shows (older non-battery model). I've tried re-creating my app, changing the name of the camera, nothing seems to sort it out. I can view the camera just fine in the google home app, but it's as if it's not even there when I look for it in the SDM API. Is there some permission set to change?